# How to allow a user ssh using password only if he's using the local network?

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, login

All users must only login using keys only except John, he can login using keys and if he's using the local network `192.168.1.x` then he could ssh using a password, but he can't do login using a password from random IPs.

I don't know how to write the rule for john. Do I do AllowUsers `john@192.168.1.x` ? But how to deny John from different ips? What happens if John connected using a different port?

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a `Match` directive.

Before you start, **make sure you have at least one account with working key-based access to the server** (or physical access).

Then edit the server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, adding your match block at the end e.g.

```
Match User john Address 192.168.1.0/24
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Note that this expresses two conditions, `User john` and `Address 192.168.1.0/24`, **both** of which must be satisfied in order for `PasswordAuthentication yes` to be applied. The `0/24` is [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) for any address in the 192.168.1.x subnet.

Now you can disable password authentication for other user-address combinations in the main body of the configuration, finding the section beginning:

```
# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
```

and changing the default

```
#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

to

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Finally, restart the service - for `systemd` based init systems, you can do that using

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh.service
```

You can test that non-matching users can no longer authenticate using passwords by forcing the client to try e.g.

```
$ ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no steeldriver@192.168.1.11
```

which should fail with a message like

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

whereas `john` should be prompted for a password:

```
$ ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no john@192.168.1.11
john@192.168.1.11's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64)
```

---

If you want password authentication to be the *preferred* mechanism for `john` when on the local network, you may need to specify that in the corresponding client configuration i.e. `~/.ssh/ssh_config`